# PHP mail issues using javascript validation

Tags: php, javascript, validation, email

I am trying to send an email from the same PHP page after Javascript validation but have some issues sending email. Can someone help me out with this?

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
        <!-- -->
        <script type="text/javascript">                                                
        function checkCheckBoxes() {

            if (document.form.inforequired.checked == true)
            {
                if (document.form.option1.checked == false && document.form.option2.checked == false && document.form.option3.checked == false && document.form.option4.checked == false && document.form.option5.checked == false && document.form.option6.checked == false && document.form.option7.checked == false && document.form.option8.checked == false  && document.form.option9.checked == false && document.form.option10.checked == false)
                {
                    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Please choose your options.";
                    return false;   
                }

                if (document.form.option8.checked == true  || document.form.option9.checked == true || document.form.option10.checked == true)
                {
                    if (document.form.address.value == "" )
                    {
                        document.getElementById('erroraddress').innerHTML = "Please enter your address.";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    document.forms["form"].submit();
                    return true;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                document.forms["form"].submit();
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Email -->
```

Here is the PHP code to send email in the else part.

```
<div id="content">
    <h1 id="formSpacingHeading"> Visitor Information </h1>

 <?if( !isset($_POST['submit'])):?> 

    <form id="form" name="form" onsubmit="return checkCheckBoxes();" action="" method="POST">

        <p id="formSpacing"><label for="username" class="iconic user" > Name <span class="required">*</span></label> <input type="text" name="username" id="username"  required="required" placeholder="Enter your name"  /></p>        
        <p id="formSpacing"><label for="usermail" class="iconic mail-alt"> E-mail address <span class="required">*</span></label> <input type="email" name="usermail" id="usermail" placeholder="Enter your E-mail ID" required="required"  /> </p>
        <p id="formSpacing"><label for="contactno" class="iconic link"> Contact number <span class="required">*</span></label> <input type="text" pattern="^\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d$" name="contact" id="contactno"  placeholder="Enter your contact number" required="required" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
    </form>

<?php else :
        $name=$_POST['username'];
        $mail=$_POST['usermail'];
        $contact=$_POST['contact'];

        $to = "admin@xxx.com";
        $subject = "New Visitor Information";
        $message = $name;
        $from = $mail;
        $headers = "From:" . $from; 
        $email = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if($email){
            echo "Thank you. We will keep you updated with the latest information.";
        }
        else{
            echo "Error processing your request. Please try again later.";
        }
?>
<? endif ?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on client-side validation.

Comment: I just figured it out. This is issue is with the code `$headers = "From:" . $from;`. But when i just use `$headers = $from;` it works!! Don't know what is the issue with the header. Is that I am using an incorrect format for the Header?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a PHP guru, but I have programmed a few basic things in it.

I think you have your if statement all wrong.

Change..

```
<?if( !isset($_POST['submit'])):?>
```

to

```
 <?if( !isset($_POST['submit'])){?>
```

Change

```
<?php else :
```

To

```
<?php } else {
```

Change

```
?>
<? endif ?>
```

to

```
 }?>
```

Comment: That is known as the [alternative control syntax](http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). It's perfectly legit.

Comment: @henry: Both the syntax works. In this i figured out that that issue is with the header. Read my above comment where I mentioned the issue with the $header in the mail function.